# Cronjob- every hour on Mondays

Tags: cron

Is there anyway to make a `cronjob` run every hour just on `Mondays` , every week.

```
* * * * 1
```

stands for `At every minute on Monday`. But I am looking for similar thing for every hour on Mondays.

Thanks,

Comment: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron expression would look like with explaination:

```
min hour day(month) month day(week)
0 0-23 * * 1
*   any value
,   value list separator
-   range of values
/   step values
```

> “At minute 0 past every hour from 0 through 23 on Monday.”

Comment: So it will run every hour on Mondays?

Comment: @Pless yes it would

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! :) @Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

**0 0-23 * * mon**

You can use the above. This will schedule your job to run at minute 0 past every hour from 0 through 23 on Monday.

This means:

```
 at 2018-05-07 00:00:00
 at 2018-05-07 01:00:00
 at 2018-05-07 02:00:00
 at 2018-05-07 03:00:00
 at 2018-05-07 04:00:00 and so on.
```

Hope this helps!